# How to improve RxJava code to API and local cache?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code where I get photos from the cache and then after that I need to get photos from API.

```
Disposable disposable = photosCacheRepository.getPhotoAttachments(workOrderId)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(photoAttachments -> {
            Disposable disposable1 = workOrdersRepository.getWorkOrderDetails(workOrderId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(workOrderDetails -> {
                  List<PhotoAttachment> photos = new ArrayList<>();
                  photos.addAll(photoAttachments);
                  photos.addAll(workOrderDetails.getAppointmentOccurrence().getPhotoAttachments());
                  if (photos.isEmpty()) {
                    view.displayNoWorkOrderPhotos();
                  } else {
                    view.displayWorkOrderPhotos(photos);
                  }
                });

            disposables.add(disposable1);
          });

      disposables.add(disposable);
```

How I can improve this code? I do not want to create two disposables as I did. Any other feedback or improvement is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There's a RxJava operator that does jut what you need. It's called flatMap ([Marbles and operator info here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)).

With this powerful operator you can get the output of the first Observable as the input of the one created by the flatMap, and then return it as an Observable.

Sorry I'm not really used to java, so the following code it's almost sure that won't work, but just to make an idea...

In your example, you could do it something like:

```
Disposable disposable = photosCacheRepository.getPhotoAttachments(workOrderId)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .flatmap(photoAttachments -> {
         workOrdersRepository.getWorkOrderDetails(workOrderId)
            .map(workOrderDetails -> {
              List<PhotoAttachment> photos = new ArrayList<>();
              photos.addAll(photoAttachments);
              photos.addAll(workOrderDetails.getAppointmentOccurrence().getPhotoAttachments());
            return photos;
            .ObserveOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(photos -> {
              if (photos.isEmpty()) {
                view.displayNoWorkOrderPhotos();
              } else {
                view.displayWorkOrderPhotos(photos);
              }...
```

I hope it helps, at least a little :)

Comment: The main problem is in photoAttachments, it is not accessible inside .subscribe()

Comment: Could you give it a try with this? again, maybe not fully functional, but now the idea es to return directly the array of photos. So when you subscribe you can use it